# Error during validation of change sets: "Required field is missing: pageOrSobjectType"

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, change-set, lightning-action-override

I'm having trouble with the deployment of a lightning app through change sets.

This is the error I am getting:

> Required field is missing: pageOrSobjectType

So I went through the source code of the change set component and found this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Tab</actionName>
        <content>Social_Home</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>Ticket_Record_Page_Social_App</content>
        <formFactor>Small</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>Case</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>Service_Resource_Record_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Small</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType xsi:nil="true"/>
    </actionOverrides>
```

As you can see the last pageOrSobjectType is empty, which is why the velidation of the change set if failing.

I'm not sure what this means and how to fix this. Seems like there's an action override on the app which is linked to no object/page. Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this?

Keep in mind that I need to deploy through change sets.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is the `App Default Assignments` you set on a Lightning page. When you go to edit this lightning page (`Service_Resource_Record_Page`), click `activation`. Do you see reference to this app in the `App Default` activation page for `phone` form factor? You can try deleting it and re-adding it.

Comment: Thing is, this page doesn't open up. I get a general error when trying to open it up in the lightning app builder: https://ibb.co/c8YQZK0
I opened a case to Salesforce but no response yet.

The weird thing is, this page seems to be connected to an object called ServiceResource, which is a standard object that needs a particular add-on license (Field Service) which we don't have.

I really don't know how this page ended up in our app...

Comment: If you go to `Setup --> Field Service`, is it enabled? Can you disable it?

Comment: It is not. I tired to enable it so I could have access to the ServicewResorce object, but apparently an add on license is needed in order to make it available.

Comment: well, the salesforce case is your best bet. Any reason it has to be change sets? If you're already looking a the metadata of application, you could just remove that reference to that object (the whole `actionoverrides`) and at least deploy it to another sandbox so you can use change sets into production (if that's a required process).

Comment: Tried that already, but doesn't solve the error on the page. Not sure if the deployment would go well that way, I haven't even tried, but I need to fix the app builder error as well, otherwise it will always be bugged and a real pain every time we need to make some sort of change on the app's pages

Btw still no answer from salesforce support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127858/discussion-between-kris-goncalves-and-robruf).

Answer (score 0):

This could be resolved if you use this line

```
        <pageOrSobjectType></pageOrSobjectType>
```

instead of your current

```
        <pageOrSobjectType xsi:nil="true"/>
```

But I am not sure if you can edit this as you are deploying through change sets. Maybe workbench have some deployment tool but not sure.